# A lower bound for the complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Let Log$(z)$ denote the principal branch of the logarithm for a complex number $z$ which is not real $\leq 0$. In various textbooks on complex analysis, I found an inequality which states
$$\frac{1}{2}|z-1| \leq |\text{Log}(z)|$$
for all $z$ with $|z-1| \leq 1/2$. The inequality is given without proofs and I have absolutely no idea how to prove this. Any hints?

Background: The inequality is given in the context of infinite products $\prod_n z_n$ and used to show the implication
$$\sum_n \text{Log}(z_n)\text{ converges absolutely}\phantom{aaa}\Longrightarrow\phantom{aaa} \sum_n z_n-1\text{ converges absolutely}$$
where all complex numbers $z_n$ are as above (i.e. not real $\leq 0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can estimate the Taylor series
$$
 \operatorname{Log}(1+w) = w - \frac 12 w^2 + \frac 13 w^3 - \frac 14 w^4 + \cdots
$$
which converges for $|w| < 1$.

For $|w| \le \frac 12$ is
$$
\begin{align}
| \operatorname{Log}(1+w)| &\ge |w| - \frac 12 |w|^2 - \frac 13 |w|^3 - \frac 14 |w|^4 - \cdots \\
&\ge  |w| - \frac 12 |w| \cdot \underbrace{\left( |w| + |w^2|+ |w|^3 + \cdots\right)}_{\le 1} \\
&\ge |w| - \frac 12 |w| = \frac 12 |w| \, .
\end{align}
$$

*Remark:* An upper bound can be obtained in the same way, so that
$$
 \frac 12 |w|  \le \operatorname{Log}(1+w)| \le \frac 32 |w|
$$
for $|w| \le \frac 12$.

Comment: oh... I just didn't thought about the fact that you can also use the triangle inequality in the form $|a+b| \geq |a|-|b|$. Many thanks!